# Set value to inherited field

Tags: go, interface

Look at my code here

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type iFormatter interface {
    SetName(name string)
    Format() string
}

type BaseFormatter struct {
    name string
}

type Formatter struct {
    BaseFormatter
}

func (f Formatter) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}
func (f Formatter) Format() string {
    return "formatted " + f.name
}

func main() {
    var formatters = []iFormatter{Formatter{}}
    formatters[0].SetName("KARL")
    fmt.Println(formatters[0].Format())
}
```

I don't understand, why the field "name" is not setted after calling SetName.

Here is the link for playground https://play.golang.org/p/Jkcjv_hFRC.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go, thinking like it's inheritance is only going to lead to more confusion later. You're only modifying copies of your values, you need pointers to modify the data in methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SetName()` method should be on a pointer, not value. Currently the `f` is a copy of the `formatters[0]` and changes to `f` are not propagated to `formatters[0]`.

The code below should do the trick.

```
func (f *Formatter) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

...

var formatters = []iFormatter{&Formatter{}}
```

You don't need to change the `Format()` method to pointer receiver though in your case it could be better to do it.

See: https://play.golang.org/p/rFmCZesbTB

Comment: Duelling updates :) - only difference is I used a pointer receiver on the Format method (no need to make a copy of the struct for formatting it)

Comment: @JohnWeldon: is you want to get pedantic, `Formatter` is only 3 words, copying it is faster than dereferencing a pointer ;)

Comment: I am not getting pedantic with _you_... I'll lose every time :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, changing these two methods like this should make it work as you expect:

```
func (f *Formatter) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}
func (f *Formatter) Format() string {
    return "formatted " + f.name
}
```

and using a pointer as

```
var formatters = []iFormatter{&Formatter{}}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eSX3mXys-a

Basically, using a pointer receiver instead of a value receiver.  Using a value receiver works on a copy of the struct instead of the original struct.

Comment: The Format method can be kept on value receiver. See my answer.

Comment: Not necessary, but there's no reason to copy the struct every time you call `Format()`

Comment: Sure, but it depends how you use struct. If it's not already has a pointer the copy may be cheaper. In this case with using interface a pointer would be better.